# check if ALL elements of a vector are in another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to loop through coloumn 1 of a matrix and return (i) when I have come across ALL of the elements of another vector which i can predefine.

```
check_vector = [1:43] %% I dont actually need to predefine this - i know I am looking for the numbers 1 to 43.
```

matrix_a coloumn 1 (which is the only coloumn i am interested in looks like this for example

1
4
3
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
16
15
18
17
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
1
3
4
2
6
7
8

We want to loop through matrix_a  and return the value of (i) when we have hit all of the numbers in the range 1 to 43. 
In the above example we are looking for all the numbers from  1 to 43  and the iteration will end round about position 47 in matrix_a because it is at this point that we hit number '2' which is the last number to complete all numbers in the sequence 1 to 43. 
It doesnt matter if we hit several of one number on the way, we count all those - we just want to know when we have reached all the numbers from the check vector or in this example in the sequence 1 to 43.

Ive tried something like:

```
completed = []
for i = 1:43
  complete(i) = find(matrix_a(:,1) == i,1,'first')
end
```

but not working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `A` as the input column vector, two approaches could be suggested here.

**Approach #1**

With [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) -

```
check_vector = [1:43]
idx = find(arrayfun(@(n) all(ismember(check_vector,A(1:n))),1:numel(A)),1)+1
```

gives -

```
idx =
    47
```

---

**Approach #2**

With customary [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
check_vector = [1:43]
idx = find(all(cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),check_vector),1)~=0,2),1)+1
```

Comment: Why `+1`? Shouldn't the answer be `46`? Nice approaches though

Comment: @LuisMendo Well I think OP meant to find the starting index of the new group. The first group ends at 46, so I thought that way.

Answer (score 1):

To find the *first entry* at which *all unique values* of `matrix_a` have *already appeared* (that is, if `check_vector` consists of all unique values of `matrix_a`): the [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function almost gives the answer:

```
[~, ind] = unique(matrix_a, 'first');
result = max(ind);
```

Comment: One of the assumptions with this one would be that there must not be a value higher than 43 in the column vector, matrix_a.

Comment: That's equivalent to my assumption _`check_vector` consists of all unique values of `matrix_a`_, isn't it?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't read that assumption `"check_vector consists of all unique values of matrix_a"`, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might have a more compact answer but is this what your after?

```
maxIndex = 0;
for ii=1:length(a)
  [f,index] = ismember(ii,a);
  maxIndex=max(maxIndex,max(index));
end
maxIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution without a loop and without any conditions on the vectors to be compared. Given two vectors `a` and `b`, this code will find the smallest index `idx` where `a(1:idx)` contains all elements of `b`. `idx` will be 0 when `b` is not contained in `a`.

```
a = [ 1 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16 15 18 17 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ...
    27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 1 3 4 2 6 7 8 50];
b = 1:43;

[~, Loca] = ismember(b,a);
idx = max(Loca) * all(Loca);
```

Some details:

- `ismember(b,a)` checks if all elements of `b` can be found in `a` and the output `Loca` lists the indices of these elements within `a`. The index will be 0, if the element cannot be found in `a`.
- `idx = max(Loca)` then is the highest index in this list of indices, so the smallest one where all elements of `b` are found within `a(1:idx)`.
- `all(Loca)` finally checks if all indices in `Loca` are nonzero, i.e. if all elements of `b` have been found in `a`.